# Is it possible to have a PAdES signature with only a timestamp?

Tags: signature, timestamping, pades

Is it possible to have a PAdES signature which only contains a timestamp from a TSA? Does this prove the content of the PDF was unaltered since timestamping?

Or is the timestamp calculated on a digital signature and does it only provide valid proof for time?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow. Can you be more descriptive in how the system operates?

Comment: @mikeazo No, that's a mistake on my part, the system didn't come up with timestamping, but that's because it was already there. OK, so that leaves one new tag: pades (or PAdES I suppose, but yeah, all lowercase). We still need a description for that.

Comment: @mikeazo:  I want to use a timestamp as digital signature. Is this possible? So the timestamp proves content + time. It seems PAdES always requires a digital signature first and the timestamp is an extention of it.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. If you look at the [PAdES specification](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts%5C103100_103199%5C103172%5C02.02.02_60%5Cts_103172v020202p.pdf), it is clear that each profile relies on at least one normal signature.

Longer answer: A timestamp and a signature serve different purposes. While a trusted timestamp does ensure the integrity of the data (alongside a notAfter date) it does not say anything about the authenticity of the the document itself, anyone can request a timestamp for any document.

The purpose of a normal signature (and PAdES is a signature standard) is to authenticate the author or issuer of a document.